# Custom Jump lists in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, jump-list

I have been looking at this: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Custom-LongList-Selector-bf8cb9ad and trying to incorporate into my app. However, its a little confusing since my data is loaded differently. Right now, I have two errors The best overloaded method match for CustomKeyGroup<.ViewModels.SoundData>.GetSoundGroups(System.Collections.Generic.List<.ViewModels.SoundData>)' has some invalid arguments

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

The error is at 'CustomKeyGroup.GetSoundGroups(mvm.Items);' from the mainpage.cs. I know the items is an issue. If you look at the link, they load the data differently w/ listmovie.add.

I know something is screwed up big time but since my data is loaded different, im struggling to get it working correctly.

Id like to have custom jumplist w/ headers by Groups (Alpha, Bravo, etc) located in my SoundModel. Here is a portion:

```
namespace T.ViewModels
{
    public class SoundModel: BindableBase
    {
        public SoundGroup NewAdds { get; set; }
        public SoundGroup Software { get; set; }

        }

        public bool IsDataLoaded { get; set; }



        public void LoadData()
        {
            // Load data into the model
            Software = CreateSoftwareGroup();
            NewAdds = CreateNewAddsGroup();


            IsDataLoaded = true;
        }

        private SoundGroup CreateNewAddsGroup()
        {
            SoundGroup data = new SoundGroup();
            data.Title = "New";
            string basePath = "assets/audio/newadds/";

               data.Items.Add(new SoundData
            {
                Title = "Test1",
                FilePath = basePath + "Test.mp3",
                Groups = "Alpha"
            });



            data.Items.Add(new SoundData
            {
                Title = "Test2",
                FilePath = basePath + "Test2.mp3",
                Groups="Bravo"
            });


            data.Items.Add(new SoundData
            {
                Title = "Test3",
                FilePath = basePath + "Test3.mp3",
                Groups= "Zulu"
            });

  private SoundGroup CreateSoftwareGroup()
        {
            SoundGroup data = new SoundGroup();

            data.Title = "Software";
            string basePath = "assets/audio/Software/";

            data.Items.Add(new SoundData
            {
                Title = "Test1",
                FilePath = basePath + "Test.mp3",
                Groups = "Alpha"
            });

            data.Items.Add(new SoundData
            {
                Title = "Test2",
                FilePath = basePath + "Test2.mp3",
                Groups="Bravo"
            });


            data.Items.Add(new SoundData
            {
                Title = "Test3",
                FilePath = basePath + "Test3.mp3",
                Groups= "Zulu"
            });
```

Here is the relevant mainpage.cs:

```
SoundData mvm = new SoundData();

            this.LongList.ItemsSource = CustomKeyGroup<SoundData>.GetSoundGroups(mvm.Items);
```

SoundGroup:

```
{
    public class SoundGroup
    {
        public SoundGroup()
        {
            Items = new List<SoundData>();
        }

        public List<SoundData> Items { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Groups { get; set; }

    }
}
```

SoundData :

```
{
    public class SoundData : ViewModelBase
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string FilePath { get; set; }
        public string Items { get; set; }
        public string Groups { get; set; }


        public RelayCommand<string> SaveSoundAsRingtone { get; set; }


        private void ExecuteSaveSoundAsRingtone(string soundPath)
        {
            App.Current.RootVisual.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                SaveRingtoneTask task = new SaveRingtoneTask();
                task.Source = new Uri("appdata:/" + this.FilePath);
                task.DisplayName = this.Title;
                task.Show();
            }
                );
        }   

        public SoundData()
        {
            SaveSoundAsRingtone = new RelayCommand<string>(ExecuteSaveSoundAsRingtone);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far from I what can see you should be calling the function as below

```
SoundModel svm = new SoundModel();
svm.LoadData();

this.LongList.ItemsSource = CustomKeyGroup<SoundData>.GetSoundGroups(svm.Software.Items);
```

or

```
this.LongList.ItemsSource = CustomKeyGroup<SoundData>.GetSoundGroups(svm.NewAdds.Items);
```

the reason is that you need to pass a `Generic.List<.ViewModels.SoundData>` in method `GetSoundGroups` and the list is contained in `SoundGroup` class. Since your data loaded is within `SoundModel` class so I could probably think of the above implementation only.

Comment: Sorry, can not upvote you since I don't have enough rep yet, but that was spot on. Errors are gone and now I just have to tweak my group headers and jumplist template.  Thank you pushpraj!

Comment: That's great the problem is solved. You can accept this answer even if you are not able to up vote. Happy coding :)